# How to prove $O(n,C) $ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

How does one prove that $O(n,C) $ is not compact?

I am guessing it can be done by showing it is not bounded.

Comment: What is $O(n,C)?

Comment: @learnmore : the orthogonal matrix of size $n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb C$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: Are you sure that it should be _orthogonal_ , not **unitary** ? Just to be sure.

Comment: Yes. It should be orthogonal.

Comment: @Evgeny The (definite) unitary groups $U(n)$ *are* compact.

Comment: Higher-level argument: $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos z& -\sin z \\
        \sin z & \cos z \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $z\in \mathbb C$

Comment: I hope it is crystal clear that for many, many  suitable $z\in \mathbb C$ we have $\cos z=1.000.000.000$ :-) More seriously the analytic function $\cos:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is surjective and has period $2\pi$, so is highly non injective. (Hence the "many, many" above.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        r_n & i\sqrt {r_n^2-1} \\
        -i\sqrt {r_n^2-1} & r_n  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $r_n\in \mathbb C$

Comment: How do I use this? Do I prove it is not sequentially compact?

Comment: I still havent solved this. Can someone help?

Comment: @Oblak Just what you said in the question: This is an unbounded subset of $O(n,\mathbb C)$ (because $r_n$ is not bounded).

Comment: Dear learnmore, it is strictly forbidden to put a complex unreal number under the square root sign .  Apart from that I plagiarized your excellent answer in a somewhat mischievous way :-)